# Stylish CakePHP form button

Tags: css, cakephp

I am trying to assign a class to form end button but when i try to style it by calling the class in css file, it do not make any effect.

Form Button:

```
echo $this->form->end('Sign Up', array('class' => 'forminput'));
```

CSS:

```
.forminput
{
width: 292px;
height: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$this->Form->submit()` to create your submit button with required options and then use `$this->Form->end()` without any params to simply close the form tag.

Comment: `$this->Form->submit('Sign up', array('class' => 'forminput'));` :-)

Comment: Thank you ADmad
Perebond: I tried this way but this is not working. ADmad was useful also i tried inspecting the element and used by default given id to the field by CAKE

Comment: The code peterbond showed will definitely work unless you do something silly like forgetting echo before that statement.